# System with messaging system an web services

Tags: web-services, message-queue, messaging

I have a project at the uni, in which I create a system which contains an android app, a cloud server and somewhere in the future a web-application.

I would use web-services to connect to the server in order to retrieve login information and other information (eg. a list of objects etc.). But I would like to use a messaging queue system to send a picture and some data with it. Is it ok to use both, or should I choose one of them? I mean what kind of issues are there if I use both?